# Why is the syntax highlighting incorrect for this answer?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249074/405017) has the following content:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var d = $('#mydiv');
    // Move down by 50px
    d.css({top:d.position().top+50+'px'});
```

If I put it here, it looks correct:

```js
var d = $('#mydiv');
// Move down by 50px
d.css({top:d.position().top+50+'px'});
```

However, in the answer the comment line is not being syntax colored as a comment. Why?

**Edit**: per the accepted answer below, I've fixed the formatting in my answer to workaround the limitation/bug, so the linked-to answer no longer demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Note that I think that this was a problem before the question was closed, so I do not believe it to be related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add blank line **before** the `<!-- language: lang-js -->` line as well.

Not sure if it's a problem with "our" parser or [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) module, but the above trick solve the issue.

Comment: @Phrogz cheers, stumbled on this here in Meta some while ago don't remember where though. :)

Comment: I had big problem with this, finally I figured it out (add a blank line before). I also searched in Meta, couldn't find anything. Decided to write a suggestion, then finally I found this by following a link in the first question in the first suggestion in "Questions that may already have your answer". Can be me being slow minded, but shouldn't this info be a part of http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting ?

Comment: @244an very true, there's already suggestion somewhere to add more details to the syntax highlight help page feel free to add this as well. :)